# OpenXML file needs repair when opened in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, .net-standard

I'm working on a function that will convert a DataTable to a `.xlsx` file using OpenXML. I'm able to create the `.xlsx` file just fine and export it, but when I open it in Excel, I get the following error:

> Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

I've tried finding a solution from similar issues, but nothing has worked.

Here's my code:

```
public MemoryStream ConvertToXLSX(DataTable table, string sheetName)
{
    MemoryStream excelStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(excelStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        var workBookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

        uint sheetID = 1;

        var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        var sheetData = new SheetData();
        sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
        string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

        if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0)
        {
            sheetID = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
        }

        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetID, Name = sheetName };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        Row headerRow = new Row();

        List<string> columns = new List<string>();

        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            cell.DataType = CellValues.SharedString;
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);
            headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
        }

        sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

        foreach (DataRow tabRow in table.Rows)
        {
            Row newRow = new Row();

            foreach (String col in columns)
            {
                var val = tabRow[col];

                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.DataType = GetCellValueType(val.GetType());
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(val.ToString());
                newRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }

            sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
        }

        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
    }

    return excelStream;
}
```

Here's an example of the data once it's been opened in Excel:

[image]

I have tried opening the file in the Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity tool and I do not get any validation errors.

Here's an screenshot of the xml hierarchy:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are outputting the wrong `cell.DataType`. In  your headers you are outputting `CellValues.SharedString` but then adding the string directly to the cell. You need to set it to `CellValues.String`.

It's hard to tell what you're outputting for the rest of the cells as you're calling `GetCellValueType(val.GetType())` which isn't listed but again, you will need to avoid using `CellValues.SharedString` if you are writing out a string.

The `CellValues.SharedString` should only be used if you write the value itself to the [SharedStringTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-the-shared-string-table).